# Multiply rows and append to dataframe by cell value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
          {'X':('a','b','c','d'),
           'Y':('a','b','d','e'),
           'Z':('a','b','c','d'),
           '#':(1,2,1,3)
                })
df
```

[image]

I would like to append the rows with a figure higher than 1 in column '#' with the figure in that row minus 1. The df should preferably 
then look like this;

[image]

Alternatively it may look like this (the rows multiplied completely);

[image]

Btw, I've searched this problem extensively, but cannot find anything that helps me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
c = df.columns[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, df['#'], axis=0)[:, 1:], columns=c)
print (df)
   X  Y  Z
0  a  a  a
1  b  b  b
2  b  b  b
3  c  d  c
4  d  e  d
5  d  e  d
6  d  e  d
```

Similar:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, df['#'], axis=0), columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   #  X  Y  Z
0  1  a  a  a
1  2  b  b  b
2  2  b  b  b
3  1  c  d  c
4  3  d  e  d
5  3  d  e  d
6  3  d  e  d
```

But if order is important:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(df['#'].max()):
    df = df[df['#'] > 0].copy()
    df['#'] -= 1
    dfs.append(df.iloc[:, 1:])

df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True) 
print (df1)
   X  Y  Z
0  a  a  a
1  b  b  b
2  c  d  c
3  d  e  d
4  b  b  b
5  d  e  d
6  d  e  d
```