# "Expand" pandas dataframe by values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I start with a dataframe that has some data and a column of quantities:

```
In:  df=pd.DataFrame({'first-name':['Jan','Leilani'],'Qty':[2,4]})

Out: Qty    first-name
     2      Jan
     4      Leilani
```

I want to create a dataframe that copies and labels the data into new lines a number of times equal to the quantity on each line. Here is what the output should look like:

```
Qty     first-name  position
2       Jan         1
2       Jan         2
4       Leilani     1
4       Leilani     2
4       Leilani     3
4       Leilani     4
```

I can do this using python like so:

```
l=[]
x=0

for idx in df.index:
    x=0
    for _ in range(df.loc[idx]['Qty']):
        x+=1
        tempSrs=df.loc[idx]
        tempSrs['position']=x
        l.append(tempSrs)

outDf=pd.DataFrame(l)
```

This is very slow. Is there a way to do this using pandas functions? This is effectively an "unpivot", which in pandas is "melt", but I wasn't able to figure out how to use the melt function to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply rows and append to dataframe by cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169882/multiply-rows-and-append-to-dataframe-by-cell-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `repeat` and `cumcount`

```
Newdf=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.Qty))
Newdf['position']=Newdf.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1
Newdf
Out[931]: 
   Qty first-name position
0    2        jan        1
0    2        jan        2
1    4        jay        1
1    4        jay        2
1    4        jay        3
1    4        jay        4
```

Comment: Brilliant answer (-:

Comment: Clever. I didn't know about the reindex and cumcount functions, thanks for putting this solution together.

Comment: @MaileCupo yw : -) happy coding

Comment: slightly edge case, but glad this question was asked. Very helpful

Answer (score 4):

### This uses almost identical concepts as Wen.

The differences are:

1. `loc` instead of `reindex` (same thing)
2. `assign` instead of `=` assignment (`assign` produces a copy)
3. Pass a `lambda` to `assign` to embed `groupby` logic

---

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.Qty)].assign(
    position=lambda d: d.groupby('first-name').cumcount() + 1
)

   Qty first-name  position
0    2        jan         1
0    2        jan         2
1    4        jay         1
1    4        jay         2
1    4        jay         3
1    4        jay         4
```

---

### Construct with `np.arange`

```
q = df.Qty.values
r = np.arange(q.sum()) - np.append(0, q[:-1]).cumsum().repeat(q) + 1
df.loc[df.index.repeat(q)].assign(position=r)

   Qty first-name  position
0    2        jan         1
0    2        jan         2
1    4        jay         1
1    4        jay         2
1    4        jay         3
1    4        jay         4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an intuitive way using `numpy.repeat` and `itertools.chain`.

For larger dataframes, this is likely to be more efficient than a `pandorable` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'first-name':['jan','jay'],'Qty':[2,4]})

lens = df['Qty'].values

res = pd.DataFrame({'Qty': np.repeat(df['Qty'], lens),
                    'first-name': np.repeat(df['first-name'], lens),
                    'Count': list(chain.from_iterable(range(1, i+1) for i in lens))})

print(res)

   Count  Qty first-name
0      1    2        jan
0      2    2        jan
1      1    4        jay
1      2    4        jay
1      3    4        jay
1      4    4        jay
```